# gWidget : is there a way to emulate user actions in testthat?

Tags: r, gwidgets, testthat

In my package, I'm using `testthat` and `gWidgetRGtk2`, I would like to know if there is a way to emulate user actions from the code line, for instance in the following I'm testing an action where the user pushes a button. So far I've been unable to test that part of the code, so I have to manually test all that.

```
require(gWidgets)
options("guiToolkit"="RGtk2")

win <- gwindow("Hello World", visible=TRUE)
obj <- gbutton("Hello world", container = gwindow(),
 handler = function(h,...) assign("test",1,.GlobalEnv))

require(testthat)
test_that("Test button click",{
     # Something here to emulate pushing button      
      expect_equivalent(test,1)
    })
```

How can I emulate the user's action ?

Comment: I don't know of any. In gWidgets2RGtk2 there is an unexported `invoke_change_handler` that could be used for this.

Comment: First I want to thank you personnally for your package that I've used for years now. And thank you for your answer. I'll try !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching quite thoroughly I think the answer is to call the handler function in the test. I didn't find any way to access the the invoke_change_handler from the source code.

Comment: Yes. That is only with gWidgets2